# как выйти из системы нажатием кнопки ESC

Tags: kernel, esc

Собрал систему на Ubuntu 16.04 пока показывает только синий экран и серые буквы
Подскажите пожалуйста как мне теперь выйти из этой системы желательно клавишей ESC

привожу исходный код kernel.c:

```
/*
*  kernel.c
*/

void kmain(void)
{
    const char *str = "my first kernel";
    char *vidptr = (char*)0xb8000;  //video mem begins here.
    unsigned int i = 0;
    unsigned int j = 0;

    /* this loops clears the screen
    * there are 25 lines each of 80 columns; each element takes 2 bytes */
    while(j < 80 * 25 * 2) {
        /* blank character */
        vidptr[j] = ' ';
        /* attribute-byte - light grey on black screen */
        vidptr[j+1] = 0x17;         
        j = j + 2;
    }

    j = 0;

    /* this loop writes the string to video memory */
    while(str[j] != '\0') {
        /* the character's ascii */
        vidptr[i] = str[j];
        /* attribute-byte: give character black bg and light grey fg */
        vidptr[i+1] = 0x17;
        ++j;
        i = i + 2;
    }
    return;
}
```

Заранее спасибо за ответ